# Unable to push notification using parse

Tags: json, parse-platform

I try trigger below script and send notification to mobile using parse. Below is my script.

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id:app-id-here" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key:rest-key-here" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{ "data": {"alert": "A test notification from Parse!"}}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/push
```

and i got error as below:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \ {"code":107,"error":"invalid json: { data: {alert:A"}
```

whats wrong with my json data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the main issue is that the 'script' needs to be on multiple lines if the backslash marks (`\`) are present, and there cannot be any spaces after backslashes.  I've edited your question to format it correctly, and it works.. returning a better error.

```
{"code":115,"error":"Missing the push channels."}
```

You just need to alter the JSON to include a channel or a query to push to, based on the docs here: https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-channels/REST

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id:app-id-here" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key:rest-key-here" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{ "channels": ["Giants"], "data": {"alert": "A test notification from Parse!"}}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/push
```

Comment: what's should i write in channels name? can i use application name to fill it?

Comment: what's should i write in channels name? can i use application name to fill it or need to write type of application = android? and may i know  what kind of tools/software you using to run this script? i use parse windows command line.

Comment: a channel that you've subscribed an installation to.  See the push docs on parse.com.  I was running it on a mac, in the terminal..

Comment: do i require to subscribed an installation first before trigger push notification?

Comment: Fosco i tried to subscribed an installation...but counter error.. can u help me? i post new question at this link

Comment: link to my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710347/unable-to-register-my-device-at-parse-push-notofication